# SSIS foreach loop container not saving base file name change

Tags: ssis

Does anyone have an answer for why when I make a change to a foreach loop container in a SSIS package it does not save?

I am trying to change the base file name and if I change it through either the edit or properties windows, the changes do not save. For example i change the Files: or File Spec: from oldfile*.txt to newfilename*.txt and when I save and go back into the edit area to confirm the change, the Files: section shows as "oldfile*.txt.

Thanks for any input you might have.

Comment: Please share your code and package structure.

Comment: Is that value being set by a variable or something?

Comment: You probably have an 'evaluate as expression' that you've forgotten about.